# Get problem when start with realtime using Pusher Nodejs

Tags: node.js, real-time, pusher

I use Pusher to start with realtime in Nodejs. But I got a problem when coding. This is my problem.

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
Error
    at new RequestError (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\Project\Book-Social-Network\backend\node_modules\pusher\lib\errors.js:13:16)
    at C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\Project\Book-Social-Network\backend\node_modules\pusher\lib\requests.js:74:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {       
  name: 'PusherRequestError',
  message: 'Request failed with an error',
  url: 'https://api-book-social.pusher.com/apps/1566147/events?auth_key=8856b27e23cd9a64d102&auth_timestamp=1679061377&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=4ee5707c207779744a1024fce29c74ce&auth_signature=c6363acc371e84e29d21b54db2a367dd3d3510cb986710a90c7c855c259d0854',
  error: FetchError: request to https://api-book-social.pusher.com/apps/1566147/events?auth_key=8856b27e23cd9a64d102&auth_timestamp=1679061377&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=4ee5707c207779744a1024fce29c74ce&auth_signature=c6363acc371e84e29d21b54db2a367dd3d3510cb986710a90c7c855c259d0854 failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api-book-social.pusher.com
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\Project\Book-Social-Network\backend\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {    
    type: 'system',
    errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
    code: 'ENOTFOUND'
  },
  status: undefined,
  body: undefined
}

Node.js v18.6.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is my code:

```
const pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: process.env.PUSHER_APPID,
  key: process.env.PUSHER_KEY,
  secret: process.env.PUSHER_SECRET, 
  cluster: process.env.PUSHER_CLUSTER,
  useTLS: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open',  () => {
  const msgCollection = db.collection('chats');
  const msgChangeStream = msgCollection.watch();

   msgChangeStream.on('change', (change) => {  
    if (change.operationType === 'insert') {
      const messageDetails = change.fullDocument; 
      pusher.trigger('messages', 'insert', {
        content: messageDetails.content,
        users: messageDetails.users, 
        sender: messageDetails.sender,  
      }); 
    } else {
      console.log('Error Trigger Pusher');
    }
  });
```

This is documentation: https://pusher.com/tutorials/mongodb-change-streams/#configuring-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

The cluster your system is connecting to is `book-social` - which isn't a Pusher cluster (https://pusher.com/docs/channels/miscellaneous/clusters/#what-clusters-exist?).

You should ensure your credentials are specified correctly as per the Pusher Dashboard.